# How to extract PDF content into .txt file with google docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-docs

How can I programmatically use google docs to programmatically extract text from pdf files?. I all ready know that there are other options, however, I am curious about if it's possible to use google docs for such purposes.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When python is used to retrieve PDF data to text data, you can achieve it using Drive API v3. But 2 steps are required for it.

1. Upload a PDF file as a Google Document
2. Download a Google Document as a TXT file

In this sample, Python Quickstart is used. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python.
Please read "Step 1: Turn on the Drive API" and "Step 2: Install the Google Client Library". If you have already known them, I'm sorry.

When you use following sample script, please modify as follows.

#### 1. Add imports

Please add following imports to Quickstart.

```
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
```

#### 2. Change SCOPES

Please change SCOPES to below.

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

#### 3. Change `main()`

Please change `main()` of Quickstart to this.

### Sample script

Sample script can be convert PDF file to TXT file. But images in the PDF file cannot be TXT file.

```
def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    pdffile = 'sample.pdf' # PDF file
    txtfile = 'sample.txt' # Text file

    mime = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
    res = service.files().create(
        body={
            'name': pdffile,
            'mimeType': mime
        },
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(pdffile, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)
    ).execute()

    dl = MediaIoBaseDownload(
        io.FileIO(txtfile, 'wb'),
        service.files().export_media(fileId=res['id'], mimeType="text/plain")
    )
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = dl.next_chunk()
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

**Script added Quickstart :**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import io

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    credential_path = os.path.join("./", 'drive-python-quickstart.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    pdffile = '../Downloads/sample.pdf'  # PDF file
    txtfile = '../Downloads/sample.txt'  # Text file

    mime = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
    res = service.files().create(
        body={
            'name': pdffile,
            'mimeType': mime
        },
        media_body=MediaFileUpload(pdffile, mimetype=mime, resumable=True)
    ).execute()

    dl = MediaIoBaseDownload(
        io.FileIO(txtfile, 'wb'),
        service.files().export_media(fileId=res['id'], mimeType="text/plain")
    )
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = dl.next_chunk()
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!... why image pdf files can not be converted to .txt files?... I tried to upload a pdf image file and  google docs converted it to a .txt file

Comment: Because the images I said was photographs without texts. Images without texts cannot be converted to text data. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: If the images include text data, this script can be convert to text data. About this, I have already confirmed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, how can I change the scopes?

Comment: Also I got `Name error: get_credentials is not defined`

Comment: At first, can I ask you about your current script? If you can tell me it, please add it to your question. Of course, you are not necessary to show your personal information.

Comment: Sure, what info do you need?. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143133/discussion-between-tanaike-and-john-doe).

Comment: Will we use a chat room? We can discuss about your script using the chat room.

Comment: Sure, see you on the chat